# conditionalPanel conditioned on multiple selectInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to set a condition on the conditionalPanel such that as long as selectInput contains 1, the conditionalPanel will show.

I am not familiar with JavaScript, can someone help?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function() {
  dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                dashboardSidebar(
                  selectInput(inputId = "month", label = "Month", choices = 1:12, multiple = TRUE)
                ),
                dashboardBody(
                  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.month == '1'", h1("success"))
                ),
                skin = "blue")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a JavaScript array `arr`, the index of element `x` in `arr` is given by `arr.indexOf(x)`. If `x` does not belong to `arr`, then `arr.indexOf(x)` returns `-1`.
So the condition you're looking for is

```
condition = "input.month.indexOf('1') > -1"
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding Correctly your issue is --you want to print "Success" till '1' is selected... If this is you issue you can try this below..

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function() {
  dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                dashboardSidebar(
                  selectInput(inputId = "month", label = "Month", choices = 1:12, multiple = TRUE)
                ),
                dashboardBody(
                  #conditionalPanel(condition = "input.month == '1'", h1("success"))
                  uiOutput("output")
                ),
                skin = "blue")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$output<-renderUI({
    if("TRUE" %in% str_detect(input$month,'1')==TRUE)
    {
      h1("Success")
    }
    else
    {
      returnValue()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please let me know if this works...